# List of intro TCS books for those who don't know much about TCS

Tags: education

If you have to recommend books for someone who wants to learn more about TCS at the introductory level such as automata theory, algorithmics, complexity theory, etc, what book(s) would you recommend for those who are interested and want to learn more about TCS, but not had any exposure to it?

Comment: I think this should be a CW question.

Comment: See [this meta discussion](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/145/98) about how to manage this question.

Comment: cstheory.SE has an [advanced list](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3253/what-books-should-everyone-read) too

Comment: @Gigili No, [community wiki is not an excuse to let unsuitable questions in](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/).

Comment: @Gilles: If this question is unsuitable, why it's still open - if not, it's asking for a list of books which is CW in every SE site.

Comment: @Gigili No. Lists of books used to be CW, but that is no longer done. Please do read the blog post I linked.

Comment: I voted to close now too. Please let us discuss [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/145/98) how to proceed with this and similar questions. We can reopen after we have established a clear policy.

Comment: is this closed because its almost duplicated on TCS.se or theres something wrong with a so-called "list question"? does anyone have a SE ref against "list questions"? seems totally reasonable to me & think it doesnt overlap with TCS.SE question because it might be more introductory level instead of advanced texts

Answer (score 9):

If you would like to have a general introduction without getting to deep into the technical details, I suggest David Harel's [Algorithmics: The Spirit of Computing](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~harel/algorithmics.html). After that, this is my favorite list:

- Michael Sipser's [Introduction to the Theory of Computation](http://www-math.mit.edu/~sipser/book.html): the best introduction to automata theory, computability and complexity.
- [Algorithms](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/algorithms.html) by  S. Dasgupta, C.H. Papadimitriou, and U.V. Vazirani: the most intuitive introduction to algorithms with stronger focus on intuition than technical proofs.
- Jon Bentley's [Programming Pearls](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/): this is not a textbook on algorithms, but it demonstrates beautifully how to use algorithm design techniques to solve real problems that irritated real programmers. :-) This might be a good start if you have some pre-knowledge on programming.

Comment: DPV is not in print yet; is it generally known?

Comment: Due to this answer's score, I included the answers in an [aggregate answer](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/485/98). Please consider removing your answer for the sake of clarity.

Comment: @Raphael DPV has been in print for several years, but it's still nicely available online. I tried not to link to commercial website like amazon.

Comment: @Dai: I see. The page you link to says "This is a penultimate draft of our soon to appear textbook.", therefore my confusion.

Answer (score 7):

- [Introduction to Algorithms](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/108986.Introduction_to_Algorithms) by Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, Stein is a popular choice, title speaks for itself.
- [Compilers: Principles, Techniques, And Tools](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/703102.Compilers) by Aho, Ulman and Sethi is a good book about compilers, has some introduction material about automata theory too.
- [Principles of Model Checking](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/026202649X) is a massive book can be used as an introduction to model checking

Comment: I find Clarke's book a bit too heavy for someone without TCS background. I know (in person) PhD students who find the book hard to understand.

Comment: @Dai, you are probably right, I've changed it to Baier's Principles of Model Checking

Comment: Can one understand model checking without basics in logics and/or automata?

Comment: The Dragon Book is certainly a good reference; is it theoretical enough, though? (I honestly don't know)

Comment: @Raphael "Principles" somewhat gives an introduction to logic (at least some necessary knowledge) and automata. It's a pretty big book too, ~980 pages. As for The Dragon Book, I thought that compilers is a rather theoretical area, isn't it?

Comment: @Daniil: Depends. You can treat compilers in very theoretical, very practical and all intermediate ways.

Comment: I certainly think the Dragon book is theoretical, moreover it's a better kind of theory since it is applicable and useful!

Comment: Due to this answer's score, I included the answers in an [aggregate answer](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/485/98). Please consider removing your answer for the sake of clarity.

Comment: @Raphael, why is your answer downvoted? Also, maybe we should have separate answers for separate topics?

Comment: In the meantime  I made the answer CW

Comment: @Daniil: Ask the downvoter. I had planned to separate into topic if/when the list became too long.

Answer (score 6):

For the mathematics needed in algorithm analysis, I recommend the one and only GKP:

[Concrete Mathematics](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/gkp.html) by Graham, Knuth, Patashnik
A comprehensive, high quality treatment of practically all the math you will need in (basic) algorithmics. It is an entertaining read and includes a wealth of exercises (and solutions).

Comment: I tried reading this book, but I didn't like it, because it all felt very... clumsy and clustered. I just didn't feel the beauty of maths there. Compare that with Sipsers' outline of automata theory or Smullyan's books on logic or even Dummit&Foote's Abstract Algebra. Maybe that's just me, tho.

Comment: I second Daniil. It's a collection of *excellent* tools for theoreticians. But it is too dry and technical to be enjoyable for beginners. I really like the books I mentioned above since they seem to have their own souls. They read as if someone is telling you stories, interesting ones.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not cover structural induction, coinduction, domain theory, and all of the stuff needed for Theory B-style TCS.

Comment: @DaveClarke: Correct. I am not sure I would expect any math-math book to contain any of that. But then, GKP is supposed to be a cs-math book. It contains no logics, either, so I should rephrase a bit.

Comment: @DaveClarke can you please recommend us some books on Theory B maths?

Answer (score 5):

[Algorithms](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/home/) 4. Edition  R. Sedgewick

[An Introduction to the Analysis of Algorithms](http://aofa.cs.princeton.edu/home/)  P. Flajolet, R. Sedgewick

[Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/ialc.html)   J. E. Hopcroft, J. D. Ullman, (R. Motwani)
The 1979 first Edition has more theoretical results that are missing in the 2001 second Edition. Haven’t look at the third Ed yet.

[Introduction to formal language theory](http://books.google.de/books/about/Introduction_to_formal_language_theory.html?id=4NVQAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y) M. A. Harrison
It is from 1978 but I still would like to see it on the list.

[Logicomix: An Epic Search for Truth](http://www.logicomix.com/en/) A. Doxiadis, C. H. Papadimitriou
Because it is totally awesome!

Again 1979
Garey and Johnson's [Computers and Intractability: A Guide to the Theory of NP-Completeness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computers_and_Intractability:_A_Guide_to_the_Theory_of_NP-Completeness)

I’d love to have TAoCP on the list but I fear, that Don Knuth’s meticulous approach is nothing that could be considered as “introductory”. Sadly...

Comment: Logicomix is certainly a gem, not saying that the others aren't.

Comment: I don't really like the way Logicomix portrayed Logicians as "insane" sort of people. Ideas in logic when explained in the right way are very down to earth and simple, and not really that "insane".

Comment: @Dai Have a look at the lives of extraordinary people like e.g. Gödel, Wittgenstein, Nash, etc. they were ... well extraordinary.

Comment: Which of those are really beginner-proof?

Comment: @Raphael IMHO all of them, otherwise I wouldn’t have posted them here. Some may have a steep learning curve but I think that’s okay.

Answer (score 4):

If you are entirely new to the field of TCS then Sipser's [Introduction to the Theory of Computation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/053494728X) is definitely the best book to get you started. I have read other introductionary books, and none of them, in my opinion, come close to Sipser's way of bringing the matter.

Other, more specific, good theoretical books are:

- Benjamin Pierce's [Types and Programming Languages](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262162091). This is theoretical computer science and logics from a different perspective.
- [Gems of Theoretical Computer Science](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540644253) by U. Schöning and R. Pruim.

Comment: Already mentioned above.

Comment: @DaveClarke I was planning to add more resources to the list as I did with my edit now, but I also wanted to emphasize how *great* Sipser's book is by mentioning it again! :-)

Comment: Pierce's book is a gem. I wish it had been around when I did my PhD (in types).

Comment: @DaveClarke I am currently using it for my bachelor thesis by recommendation of my advisor and I am also very impressed by it!

Comment: You might also want to look into Bob Harper's online book [Practical Foundations of Programming Languages](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/plbook/book.pdf). It's incomplete and a little more advanced, by much more comprehensive.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I will take a look at it later today. I see that you are a professor at KUL, I am coming there next year to study Secure Software (Veilige software). What a small world.

Comment: Schöning's Gems is certainly nothing for starters.

Answer (score 3):

*This is an aggregate answer that contains books from answers with score at least five. Please discuss its content in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2710/computer-science).*

#### Algorithms & Data Structures

- [Introduction to Algorithms](http://mitpress.mit.edu/catalog/item/default.asp?ttype=2&tid=11866) by Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, Stein (3rd ed 2009)
  A comprehensive treatment of basic algorithms and data structures and their analysis without digging too deep.
- [Algorithms](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/%7Evazirani/algorithms.html) by Dasgupta, Papadimitriou, Vazirani (2006)
  The most intuitive introduction to algorithms with stronger focus on intuition than technical proofs.

#### Computability & Complexity

- [Introduction to the Theory of Computation](http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Esipser/book.html) by Sipser (2nd edition 2005)
  The best introduction to automata theory, computability and complexity.

#### Formal Languages & Automata

- [Compilers: Principles, Techniques, And Tools](http://dragonbook.stanford.edu/) by Aho, Ulman and Sethi (2nd ed 2006)
  The standard book about compilers; very comprehensive. Touches automata theory, too.

#### Applied Theory

- [Principles of Model Checking](http://mitpress.mit.edu/catalog/item/default.asp?ttype=2&tid=11481) by Baier, Katoen (2008)
  Massive book that an be used as a comprehensive introduction to model checking.
- [Programming Pearls](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/) by Jon Bentley (2nd ed 1999)
  Not a textbook on algorithms but demonstrates beautifully how to use algorithm design techniques to solve real problems. Might be a good start if you have some pre-knowledge on programming.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, or if it's meant to, it is not a good answer. Do you mean someone starting TCS needs to read all of these books? If not, how would they choose? Keep in mind that by your rule, this answer is likely to grow to contain [hundreds of books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read)

Comment: @Raphael Are you it's polite to ask someone else to remove his/her own answer? Usually the asker himself/herself can do the job of aggregating his favorite answers by modifying his/her own question text, but I've never seen anyone force another person to delete his/her own post to create his own answer. This cs stackexchange is getting weird with these narcissistic behaviors.

Comment: @Raphael: Making it a CW doesn't make it right to ask someone to delete his/her own answer. It's like saying I'm gonna writing a book/survey paper (which I will publish online for free), so I go around and ask all authors whose papers I cite to take down their own papers to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Raphael I don't see any where in the CC licenses saying that my work will be eventually requested taken down by someone else. I don't know what sort of fantasy you have with SE, but it's definitely not Wikipedia. I know you work hard to "moderate" this website, but please also respect someone else's freedom of speech and privacy, and simply let the up/down votes take care of the rest. I think the goal of cs SE is to provide a more friendly forum than cstheory SE to beginners, but the micro level of management you proposed here made it so much worse.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2823/discussion-between-raphael-and-dai)

Answer (score 3):

Some good books covering the Theory B part of TCS:

- **Logic in CS**: *Logic in Computer Science: Modelling and Reasoning about Systems* By Michael Huth and Mark Ryan.
  Broad coverage of various uses of logic in computer science. About 3rd year undergraduate level.
- **The Lambda Calculus**: *Lambda-Calculus and Combinators. An introduction* by J. Roger Hindley and Jonathan P. Seldin.
  Introduces the lambda calculus, which is an essential ingredient in the foundations of programming languages. About 3rd year undergraduate level.
- **Lead in to domain theory**: *Introduction to Lattices and Order (2nd ed.)* by Davey, B. A. and Priestley, H. A.  Cambridge University Press. (2002).
  Covers a very useful topic, especially if you plan to work with semantics. It is a bit more mathematical than the other topics, but the early chapters are certainly at an advanced undergraduate level.
- **Semantics**: *Semantics with Applications: An Appetizer* by Hanne Riis Nielson and Flemming Nielson.
  A really nice introduction to programming language semantics. Rather than going deep into any particular formalism, it gives a broad presentation and includes applications generally not considered in other books on semantics. Could possibly be useful for 2nd year undergraduates.

Comment: I don't know any of those even by reputation, so I can't say wether they are any good (even though I am inclined to take your word for it). :/

Comment: I've added a description of each book. All are good.