# Supporting material for theory of computation

Tags: automata

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of intro TCS books for those who don’t know much about TCS](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/454/list-of-intro-tcs-books-for-those-who-dont-know-much-about-tcs)

Im taking a course on Theoretical  computer Science. and I use Sipser's `Introduction to Theory of Computation` as my reference manual. However, many times I find myself lost in the proofs. Ive tried following Shai Simpson's online lectures ,but would prefer something more watered down and easier to understand. Im open to any pointers/strategies or resources.

Comment: How much do you expect proofs to be watered down without becoming non-proofs? I think you should stick to TCS books if you hope to learn something; maybe another author has a style you can work with?.

Comment: well I was only looking for an "aide" to follow the sipser book.Some sort of online lecture/notes etc. My prof at uni isnt doing a great job :\

Comment: I am not sure this is the right place for this, sorry. If you feel like you should get an answer here, please flag your question so the other mods can weigh in, or open a thread on [meta]. You might want to try [chat], too. (With a bit of patience, it's not too crowded there these days.)

Comment: I googled around a bit; maybe the lecture videos provided [here](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs373/fa2011/lectures/) help?

Comment: I will look into the link there. Thanks! Could you migrate the question to CS Meta then?

Comment: No; this is not a meta question. It would be the place for a new question, should you wish to discuss the closing of this question.